# Cacti memory graph not showing correct graph value?

Tags: linux, graph, cacti

Kindly help. I am stuck. Graph are getting spikes ..but the value is not showing correctly although SNMP get the value correctly.Please throw some light.

Comment: Can you add screen shot? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You need to give more information.  A picture of the graph, data sample, describe what you are getting, what you think you should  be getting, and why.  Also, giving the configuration details would help.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information, such as the snmpwalk / snmpget command used as well as the returned output when executed from the command line.